Cannot locate any element on the page by Robot Framework
I am working on Robot Framework tests for SuiteCRM instance with Browser library. I cannot locate any element on the page with list of Accounts.
HTML code of the page  is located here:https://autera.cz/accounts_html.html
For example I want to click on the table title ACCOUNTS with //scrm-module-title[@class='list-view-title'].
I can reach it locally with browser but not by Robot Framework. I cannot see any iframe or other similar tag. What is the issue?
Thank you in advance for suggestions.
I want to locate the element. But without any results.
This is the part of code with the issue:
*** Test Cases ***
Check list of accounts
    [Documentation]    Navigate to list of accounts and check it
    ${LEAD}=    Load dataset from file "fixtures/account1.json"
    Navigate into List of "Accounts"
    Click    div[class='app-shell']
    Click    //scrm-navbar-ui
    Click    xpath=//scrm-module-title[@class='list-view-title']


What is the error you are getting?

This is error message from Robot:   TimeoutError: locator.click: Timeout 10000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('xpath=//scrm-navbar-ui')
locator resolved to …
attempting click action
waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
element is not visible - waiting...
Tip: Use "Set Browser Timeout" for increasing the timeout or double check your locator as the targeted element(s) couldn't be found.
